# How can I allow limited access to API created in aws API gateway?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I have a API in AWS API gateway.
I wants to give Limited access to the user how can I do that?
or how can I create Signed url if possible for the API access does anyone has any idea?
I can Disable from the API Gateway Console but can I give the time or limited access to the user?

Comment: The answer depends, in part, on which type of back-end service your API integrates with: is it Amazon Lambda, or HTTP Proxy, or AWS Service Proxy?  Or more than one of the above?  There can be different implications depending on what's behind it.

Comment: Also, please clarify "limited access."  Do you mean an access control/authentication/authorization mechanism generally, or user specific restrictions?

Comment: I am working with aws lambda

Comment: yes the authorization and limited I mean is I should be able to allow the user for some specific time to access my API.is it possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Cognito to authenticate your user against Google/Twitter/Facebook. Then in Cognito you configure the Role the temporary IAM user should have that Cognito returns. This Role should at least have rights to call your API Gateway.

In the API Gateway you can configure your endpoints so that it is required to have a valid IAM authentication.

Lastly if you want to restrict the user, you can make a call to Cognito and remove/adjust his account to block him.